# Can a jetty 5 custom classloader exclude specific jar files in a war?

Tags: jsf, jetty, classloader

I've got a large code base that currently runs on JSF 1.1 on embedded Jetty 5.1.14 server (Servlet 2.4). I've managed to get a JSF 2.0.9 app running on this version of Jetty even though I'd expected to require servlet 2.5, and I add EL 2.1.2 & the JSF jar to WEB-INF/lib. This works on a jetty config that excludes JSF 1.1.

The production environment consists of a large number of war and jar files on a single server instance.

JSF 1.1 is currently in the server ext/lib folder, and in a single war file I'd like to include the JSF 2 jar in the WEB-INF/lib. This is not possible as the server JSF version will load first and cause classpath pollution.

However would it be possible to eliminate the JSF 1.1 jar loading in just the one war file with a custom classloader? The documentation seems to cater for the case of adding paths to the classpath rather than excluding things. I wasn't clear whether it's loaded in the context of the server as a whole or just the war.

A little more information: Another potential solution is to simply upgrade to Jetty 8 and JSF 2.1+. Apart from convincing management that this is a good idea, we use an old WebMethods7 version, this has a graphical layout tool that produces some XML that is translated by a Component Application Framework, which uses the JSF APIs to generate content (so only a very few JSPs). This would simply be a case of seeing if it works, and if not having a total rethink because of the need to keep supporting this WebMethods "code".

The main goal here is to ultimately run up to date software although not necessarily in one step.

Answer (score 1):

Jetty5 is incredibly old at this point and I would recommend working on the update to jetty8, or waiting a couple of months and making the jump to jetty9 which we are currently releasing milestones for.  Changes in the newer jvm's since then alone are enough reason to update your jetty container.

I don't know if this approach was supported in jetty5 or not, but in jetty6 we have ability on the webapp context to modify the classes that are exposed to the context via system and server classes.  If those hooks exists then you should be able to tweak that specific context to not expose the classes in the jar in ext/lib.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please could you give me a pointer to the system and server classes you reference. Thanks.

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Jetty_Classloading - this is the concept that I know exists in 6-9, you'll have to poke around in jetty 5 to see if it exists there.